# Can´t open an submitted sap app (via Eclipse Neon) on Fiori LaunchPad

Tags: eclipse, sapui5

I'm going to try to be as more specific I can be.

So I'm building an Planning Calendar app on SapUi5 similar to this [one](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/planning-calendar/).

But after I 'share project' on Eclipse and try to open the app on Fiori LaunchPad it gives me this error:

[image]

[image: Version of SAP UI5]

[image: Running App]

I'm new to this language and any kind of help will be appreciated. If you need anything else please let me know.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It says that it is trying to add an element with the id "app", but there is already such an id on the page and so it fails. Somewhere in your app you are causing this to happen, so you'll need to figure out where it is and change that id.

Comment: @EthanJewett That's the strange thing! I tried to found that 'error', nothing appeared. I have refreshed the LaunchPad and now that error disappeared but I have a new one now.... I've already updated the image.

Comment: The first error about the component-preload.js isn't the problem. That's a normal error when no component-preload.js exists and it won't stop your app from loading. It appears your app is trying to load sap.m.PlanningCalendar and it doesn't exist. That's the error you'll have to try to resolve. What version of UI5 are you on?

Comment: The version of UI5 is 1.28

Comment: PlanningCalendar wasn't introduced until 1.34 - https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.PlanningCalendar.html

Comment: Let me get this right then. I've developed this PlanningCalendar app on UI5 1.28 on SAP Web IDE and it works perfectly (if you want i can upload some pics). Then I transfered the project to Eclipse Neon because I need it to do a couple of things. And now if I want to open this app, similar to PlanningCalendar, on LaunchPad I can't because of the 1.28 version? Sorry if it's to confusing

Comment: Are you sure you were using 1.28 on WebIDE? Usually WebIDE uses the latest SAPUI5 version. Here is the 1.28 API reference where I do not see a PlanningCalendar (though I may be overlooking it): https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.28.44/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.html

Comment: I'm going to upload a couple of pics so you can see if thats it

Comment: @EthanJewett There

Comment: When you test your app in WebIDE and it works, see what the value of the variable `sap.ui.version` is on the console?

Comment: 1.46.7 ............ But why and how is this possible?

Comment: Not sure. You'll probably have to share your app for someone to fully diagnose. It's possible that you used example code in your index.html and are pulling UI5 from a CDN or something instead of using the local one.

Comment: Also possible that it's a WebIDE bug. It wouldn't be the first time :-/

Comment: I've created a new project, on version 1.28. I copied the previous code and paste it and suddenly it updates to version 1.46..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some time searching and analyzing the code with my fellow partners the only answer we can assume is the answer of @Ethan Jewett which is: 'Not sure. You'll probably have to share your app with someone to fully diagnose. It's possible that you used example code in your index.html and are pulling UI5 from a CDN or something instead of using the local one.'. If you want to understand (well) the problem please check the comments. Thanks to Ethan for all his help!!